# show alternate text in place of an image, before image loads

Tags: javascript, html

How can I show text in place of an image, before the image loads?

Because on an HTML website I have an image as the title of the page, so the page loads completely, and the title image comes in later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<h1><img src="heading.png" alt="Some nice heading here"
         width="600" height="80"></h1>
```

Use the `alt` attribute and set the image dimensions (in HTML or in CSS) to ensure that browsers can allocate appropriate space before getting the image. You can also apply CSS styling to the `img` element, e.g. font face, size, and color; on modern browsers, the styling will be applied to the alternate text when the image has not been got yet (or ever). Using code above, you can set the styles on the `h1` element.

Altenatively, use just (styled) text for the heading initially but replace it by the image using JavaScript:

```
<h1 style="width: 600px; height: 80px">Some nice heading here</h1>
<script>
new Image('heading.png'); // preloads the image
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
h1.innerHTML = '<img src=heading.png alt="' + h1.innerHTML + '">';
</script>
```

Comment: how do you determine the image dimensions? (point being, there often *isn't* a way to do this.)

Comment: @Michael how do you do it then?

Answer (score 3):

How about this-

```
<div id="img">some text</div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#img").innerHTML="<img src="myimg.jpg">"
  });
 });
 </script>
```

jQuery is a good option to do this:-)

Answer (score 1):

use the Alt tag but even that is no guarantee:

```
<img src="yourimagepath" alt="Title Text" title="Title Text" />
```

Alternatively, you can use a JS hack: Set the title of your page as text and replace the content of the title container with the image using JS after the full page load.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically load images in jQuery with only a very small amount of code. You can do smooth things like place "Loading..." animations or AJAX spinners in place of your content if you like this way.

From a comment on the jQuery documentation

```
var _url = "image.jpg";

// set up the node / element
_im =$("<img>");

// hide and bind to the load event
_im.hide();
_im.bind("load",function(){ $(this).fadeIn(); });

// append to target node / element
$('body div#target').append(_im);

// set the src attribute now, after insertion to the DOM
_im.attr('src',_url);
```

in pseudocode, create and hide an image element, assign an onload event handler, set the src attribute loading the image dynamically. The handler fades the image in smoothly.

Comment: His question isn't tagged `jQuery`

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use jQuery for only this (unless the OP is already using jQuery. It is an overkill imo

Comment: Yes, I wanted to provide a "smooth" solution rather than relying on alt text which isn't as nice a user experience.

Comment: How's the alt text not a nice user experience? Alt text actually provides a better user experience for users with non-visual output devices. Additionally, a small bit handwritten js code should be sufficient for the OP's purposes

Comment: I agree alt should be there for usability purposes. "the title image comes in later" implies some kind of smooth user experience. Maybe I just read too much into "comes in" and "later".