# Image "alt" or "title" property does not shown. A blank white is appears

Tags: angularjs, image, browser

I have disabled the image option in the browser settings and rendered the image.
On the initial load, the image is not displaying the "alt" or "title" attribute and it shows empty white.

After ctrl+R, It shows the image alt or title text in the browser.

```
<img alt="I am here" src="test.png">
```

If I empty the "src" tag, then it appears correct.

Also,  **Is there any way to deduct the image settings from javascript ?**

How do I solve the page load image "alt/title" display issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Alt text is not reliably shown before an image loads. If you want to show text prior to the loading of an image, you should consider using a javascript based solution. The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979186/show-alternate-text-in-place-of-an-image-before-image-loads) shows a good way to do this. Alt and Title serve different purposes. Title is the text that displays when a user leaves the mouse over the image.

Regarding your second question - what do you mean by deduct the image settings? I see you have tagged the post AngularJS - so if you have an array of objects in your controller like so:

```
var controller = function($scope) {
    $scope.image = {
        src: "img.png",
        txt: "Text here"
    };
}

var app = angular.module('myApp');
var module = app.controller('Controller', controller);
```

You could access the data from that in your view like so:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller">
    <div id="image-placeholder">{{images[0].txt}}</div>
    <!-- from the other post -->
    <script>
        new Image('{{image.src}}'); // preloads the image
        var placeholder= document.getElementById('image-placeholder');
        placeholder.innerHTML = '<img src={{image.src}} alt="' + placeholder.innerHTML + '">';
    </script>
</body>
```

This snippet would be a good candidate for a directive, but can also be used as is.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this fix is too expensive for considering all the images across the application. Is there anything that can help to achieve through img directive in angular ?

Comment: @user1764882 I don't think this would be too expensive to use. You could create an angular directive to do this fairly easily. I'm not in a good spot to write one for you right now. The standard image directive (`ng-src`) just gets the source once angular is loaded. I would think that that would not be helpful. But you could turn the above snippet into a directive very easily.